# Call Controller's Action in MVC through jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I create the Button in jqgrid row by using the Formatter.

Now I try to call the Controller's Action method by the following way,

```
{

name: 'Save', index: 'Save', width: 100, sortable: false,

formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {

return "input type='button' value='store' onclick=location.href=@Url.Action("Action", "Controller") ";

}

}
```

But,I cant able to call the action.How to solve This?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change :

```
onclick=location.href=@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")
```

to this:

```
onclick=location.href='@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")'
```